# Utilizing Azure Custom Script Extensions to maintain a custom PowerShell module across multiple servers

Tags: azure

I'm trying to automate some tasks at work and someone gave me an idea that we could utilize Azure Custom Script Extensions to maintain a custom PowerShell module across multiple servers.

The script is located on our Azure DevOps, but I assume I could create a Pipeline that moves it to storage account after a pull request is completed.

However, my question is - how does Custom Script Extension work in the first place and would it be suitable for my needs, which are having an up-to-date PowerShell module available on multiple servers?

Answer (score 0):

Were you able to find the answer on your question?

As I know, after the Custom Script Extension is installed the script will be executed once.

Below code snippet shows how you could deploy Custom Script Extension on Multiple VMs:

```
$CustomerScriptExtension = "yourCSEName"
$AllVMs = Get-AzureRMVM  #get all VMs
$CntOfVMs = 0;
foreach($vm in $AllVMs)
{
    try
    {
        $CntOfVMs = $CntOfVMs + 1
        Write-Host "VMCount:" $CntOfVMs
        #Get the VM details of that instance
        $vmDetails = Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $vm.ResourceGroupName -Name             vm.Name
        #Check if already an extension exists of type Custome Script Extension
        $cseExtension = $vmDetails.Extensions | where { $_.Publisher -eq 
"Microsoft.Compute" -and $_.VirtualMachineExtensionType -eq "CustomScriptExtension" }
 
        # If Extension already exists remove the extension
        if ($cseExtension)
        {
            #Remove the extension
            Write-Host "Removing existing extension on VirtualMachine:" $vm.Name
            Remove-AzureRmVMCustomScriptExtension -ResourceGroupName 
  $vm.ResourceGroupName -VMName $vm.Name -Name $cseExtension.Name
               Write-Host "Completed Removal of existing extension on VirtualMachine:" 
  $vm.Name
        }
       
        try
        {
            Write-Host "Installing extenstion on VirtualMachine :" $vm.Name
            Set-AzureRmVMCustomScriptExtension -ResourceGroupName 
  $vm.ResourceGroupName -VMName $vm.Name -Location $vm.Location -FileUri 
  PathToyourPowerShellCodeToUpdateVMGoesThere.ps1 -Run "InstalluptodatePowerShell.ps1" -name 
  $CustomerScriptExtension
            Write-Host "completed Extension installation on VirtualMachine  :" 
  $vm.Name 
        }
        catch
        {
            Write-Host "Error installing extension on  VirtualMachine  :" $vm.Name

   
        }
    }
       
    catch
    {
         Write-Host "Error in setting extension on VM:" $vm.Name 
    }
}
```